# multicast receive wrong message

Tags: java, multicast

I'm working on MulticastSocket. Testing with Websphere 8.0.0.5 on AIX 7. The problem is getting wrong message from sender. Testing scenario is:
1. run sendMulticast (new thread)
2. run receiveMulticast (new thread)
3. run receiveMulticast (new thread)

The first receiver thread always receives the right message. Secondary receiver thread receives wrong message.

But interesting thing is i tried this on same machine (AIX 7) with Java 6 as console application and every thing is OK.

Here is the code:

```
    static final int port = 9999;
    static final String multicastAddress = "224.2.2.3";


    public static void sendMulticast()  {
        MulticastSocket socket = null;
        DatagramPacket outPacket = null;
        byte[] outBuf;

        long t= System.currentTimeMillis();

        //run 60 seconds
        long end = t+60000;

        try {
            socket = new MulticastSocket();
            String msg;

            while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
                msg = "//172.21.131.242:51860/SERVICE_EXECUTION_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ERROR_CODES_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ACCOUNTING_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/CONFIGURATION_ITEMS_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/REFERENCE_DATA";
                outBuf = msg.getBytes();

                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(multicastAddress);
                outPacket = new DatagramPacket(outBuf, outBuf.length, address, port);

                socket.setTimeToLive(32);
                socket.send(outPacket);


                System.out.println("Server sends : " + msg);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        socket.close();
    }


    public static void receiveMulticast() {
        MulticastSocket socket = null;
        DatagramPacket packet = null;
        byte[] inBuf = new byte[1500];

        long t= System.currentTimeMillis();

        //run 60 seconds
        long end = t+60000;

        try {
            // Prepare to join multicast group
            socket = new MulticastSocket(port);
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(multicastAddress);
            socket.joinGroup(address);

            while(System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
                packet = new DatagramPacket(inBuf, inBuf.length);
                socket.receive(packet);
                byte[] payload = packet.getData();
                String msg = new String(payload);
                System.out.println("From " + packet.getAddress() + " Msg : " + msg);
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        socket.close();
    }
```

And here is the log:
You can see at 10:39:47:675 and 10:39:48:177 missing string is coming to receiver.

What could be the problem?

```
[2/20/13 10:39:45:162 EET] 0000003a SystemOut     O Server sends : //172.21.131.242:51860/SERVICE_EXECUTION_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ERROR_CODES_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ACCOUNTING_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/CONFIGURATION_ITEMS_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/REFERENCE_DATA
[2/20/13 10:39:45:163 EET] 0000003b SystemOut     O From /172.21.131.242 Msg : //172.21.131.242:51860/SERVICE_EXECUTION_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ERROR_CODES_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ACCOUNTING_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/CONFIGURATION_ITEMS_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/REFERENCE_DATA
[2/20/13 10:39:45:665 EET] 0000003b SystemOut     O From /172.21.131.242 Msg : //172.21.131.242:51860/SERVICE_EXECUTION_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ERROR_CODES_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ACCOUNTING_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/CONFIGURATION_ITEMS_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/REFERENCE_DATA
[2/20/13 10:39:45:665 EET] 0000003a SystemOut     O Server sends : //172.21.131.242:51860/SERVICE_EXECUTION_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ERROR_CODES_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ACCOUNTING_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/CONFIGURATION_ITEMS_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/REFERENCE_DATA
[2/20/13 10:39:46:167 EET] 0000003a SystemOut     O Server sends : //172.21.131.242:51860/SERVICE_EXECUTION_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ERROR_CODES_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ACCOUNTING_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/CONFIGURATION_ITEMS_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/REFERENCE_DATA
[2/20/13 10:39:46:168 EET] 0000003b SystemOut     O From /172.21.131.242 Msg : //172.21.131.242:51860/SERVICE_EXECUTION_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ERROR_CODES_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ACCOUNTING_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/CONFIGURATION_ITEMS_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/REFERENCE_DATA
[2/20/13 10:39:46:672 EET] 0000003a SystemOut     O Server sends : //172.21.131.242:51860/SERVICE_EXECUTION_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ERROR_CODES_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ACCOUNTING_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/CONFIGURATION_ITEMS_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/REFERENCE_DATA
[2/20/13 10:39:46:673 EET] 0000003b SystemOut     O From /172.21.131.242 Msg : //172.21.131.242:51860/SERVICE_EXECUTION_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ERROR_CODES_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ACCOUNTING_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/CONFIGURATION_ITEMS_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/REFERENCE_DATA
[2/20/13 10:39:47:173 EET] 0000003a SystemOut     O Server sends : //172.21.131.242:51860/SERVICE_EXECUTION_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ERROR_CODES_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ACCOUNTING_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/CONFIGURATION_ITEMS_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/REFERENCE_DATA
[2/20/13 10:39:47:174 EET] 0000003b SystemOut     O From /172.21.131.242 Msg : //172.21.131.242:51860/SERVICE_EXECUTION_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ERROR_CODES_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ACCOUNTING_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/CONFIGURATION_ITEMS_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/REFERENCE_DATA
[2/20/13 10:39:47:674 EET] 0000003a SystemOut     O Server sends : //172.21.131.242:51860/SERVICE_EXECUTION_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ERROR_CODES_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ACCOUNTING_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/CONFIGURATION_ITEMS_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/REFERENCE_DATA
[2/20/13 10:39:47:675 EET] 0000003b SystemOut     O From /46.50.52.50 Msg : CE_EXECUTION_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ERROR_CODES_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ACCOUNTING_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/CONFIGURATION_ITEMS_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/REFERENCE_DATA131.242:51860/REFERENCE_DATA
[2/20/13 10:39:47:676 EET] 0000003c SystemOut     O From /172.21.131.242 Msg : //172.21.131.242:51860/SERVICE_EXECUTION_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ERROR_CODES_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ACCOUNTING_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/CONFIGURATION_ITEMS_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/REFERENCE_DATA
[2/20/13 10:39:48:176 EET] 0000003a SystemOut     O Server sends : //172.21.131.242:51860/SERVICE_EXECUTION_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ERROR_CODES_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ACCOUNTING_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/CONFIGURATION_ITEMS_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/REFERENCE_DATA
[2/20/13 10:39:48:177 EET] 0000003b SystemOut     O From /46.50.52.50 Msg : CE_EXECUTION_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ERROR_CODES_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/ACCOUNTING_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/CONFIGURATION_ITEMS_CACHE|//172.21.131.242:51860/REFERENCE_DATA131.242:51860/REFERENCE_DATA
```

Comment: It seems there is another sender on the network, regardless, you should not open any threads in websphere. and for sockets you should probably use a JCA resource adapter.

Comment: i'm sure that i'm only the one sender on the network (on this multicast address and port) and i'm not opening new threads in websphere. each thread is a web service request

Comment: What is this IP 46.50.52.50 ? is is another IP of the sender machine ?

Comment: no there is nothing on this ip address. i think datagram package is corrupted. in parallel i'm monitoring network, there is only one sender and it is 172.21.131.242

Comment: Any chance you start listening after the package have been sent ?

Comment: no i cant track the package :(